# how to generate auto increment id in hibernate only if identity column is null in hibernate 6.X?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity-framework-6

Use case is while saving new entity there is two options for IdentityColumn

1. Generate auto_increment id if id column is null( works perfect with  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`
2. do not generate auto increment id if id column is not null and use the same id which we are manually setting while saving entity. This was also working fine with combination of  Hibernate assigned generator with identity generator by using below Annotations on identity column.

   ```
   @Id
   @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY,  generator = "CustomIdGenerator")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "CustomIdGenerator", strategy = "com.CustomIdentityGenerator ")
   private Long id;
   ```

Both of the use cases was working fine with hibernate version 5.X with below code of 'CustomIdentityGenerator'

```
public class CustomIdentityGenerator extends IdentityGenerator {

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister(null, object).getClassMetadata().getIdentifier(object, session);
        return id != null && id != Integer.valueOf(0) ? id : super.generate(session, object);
    }
}
```

However after update to hibernate version 6.X  Generate method is not present in **'IdentityGenerator'**. Tried multiple ways to override but nothing works.

Is it even possible in hibernate 6.X to achieve this use case?

Comment: generate method is now part of IdentifierGenerator interface and can be used together wit @IdGeneratorType annotation. More details here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-IdGeneratorType

Comment: That is also not working, already tested

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue as i m using Hibernate 6.2.5 Final, on exploring I found `IdentifierGenerator`interface which have `generate` method by implementing `IdentifierGenerator`to your class `CustomIdentityGenerator` you can achive what you need,

```
public class CustomIdentityGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) {
    
    \\ your logic
    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my complete class with logic in case someone needs it.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator;
import org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister;


public class NativeIfNotAssignedIdentityGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object entity)
      throws HibernateException {

    final Random r = new Random();
    final Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            while(true) {
            int num = r.nextInt(4) + 1;
            if (s.contains(num) == false) {
                s.add(num);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Serializable idOld;
    Serializable idNew = "";
    EntityPersister persister = session.getEntityPersister(null, entity);
    // Determine if an ID has been assigned.
    idOld = (Serializable) persister.getIdentifier(entity, session);
    if (idOld == null) {
      idNew = (Serializable) s;
    }
    return idNew;
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work in Hibernate 6.2

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, hybrid before/after execution ID generators are no longer allowed in hibernate 6.2+, see [hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16692)